# Batch file when using WinSCP and command prompt

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd, winscp

I am currently writing a script that calls WinSCP, connects an SFTP session, transfers a group of files from a local server to a remote server, closes the connection, then moves the local file to an archive. An alternate acceptable solution would be to copy the file to archive and then delete it from the source directory.

The problem I am having is that I can get WinSCP to open, connect and transfer the files, but after that the commands are ignored and I am unable to automate the connection close, file move or copy and the deletion and closing of command prompt. What is the best way to do this?

My `FTP.bat` file that connects the session and calls the script -

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console /command "lcd d:\bofa_ftp\out" /script=script.txt savedsession@winscpname.com
```

My script file that puts the file and closes the connection -

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
option exclude script.txt
put *.txt
close
```

When I add any commands to either the bat or the script they are ignored.

Comment: Take a look at the _console/scripting mode_ section of the [docs](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline)... You can pass a separate batch file to the .exe to execute the commands you need once connected apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Commands after `close` are definitely not ignored. Your problem might be that you are trying to put Windows commands to WinSCP script. Note that there are no commands in WinSCP to move local files.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying using Winscp3, try with plink.exe.

Plink is the best option to transfer files from winscp3 to your local.By using scp command we can transfer file from winscp to local as well as one folder in to another folder in winscp.

```
scp username@atechguideserver1.com:/data/tmp/samplscp.txt username@atechguideserver2.com:/data/tmp/dir/tech
```

Please refer to: http://99students.com/move-files-in-unix/